# jquery and ajax query in rails 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

---

hi people

I don't know much about ajax - jquery. And right now I need to use some functionality with them.

In a form (sales model) I have the following code:

```
<div>
    <%= f.label :product_id, "Product" %>
    <%= f.collection_select( :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name, options={} ) %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :price, "Price" %>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
```

The idea is: when I select a "product" I want to show the price of that product automatically in the "price" text-field. I have a table where I store the price of each product.

I tried [this example](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/building_with_ajax_and_rails/) but didn't work.

Hope you can help me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking about what the jQuery code would look like, this should do the trick:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET', // or 'POST', 'PUT', whatever
   url: '/Url/To/Some/Route',
   data: { productId: $('#product_id') },
   success: function(response)
   {
       // assuming data comes back as JSON like so: { price: 30.00 }
       $('#price').val(response.price);
   }
});
```

Comment: actually, I need to know everything, because is the first time I use jquery and ajax. So I would like to know where should I write the jquery code, what should I add to my code... any way, thanks for your help